# how to find which file has code to insert data into table in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, cron

I have one table in my database as `mag_sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`.

I want to find a PHP file which has code to add the data into the above table. I think the file which adds data into above table is a *crontab* file. I don't know the location of crontab file.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is adding through `crontab` file which you can find in `Mage_Sales` module.

In [app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml#L1779) this file the `crontab` setting is defined.

The php code you can find it here [app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Observer.php](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Observer.php#L228)

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your help. I have found out above mentioned files. Now i want to search for the code which causes the log data to be added into the table.